Nonconvex quadratic objective with quadratic constraint
I need some hints to prove whether problems P1 and P2 are equivalent or not. Any help will be appreciated.
$
P1: \min_{x}  | x^H C^H C x - d |^2 ~~ {s.t.} ~~ x^H P^H P x = a, 
$
$
P2: \min_{x}  | x^H C^H C x - d |^2 ~~ {s.t.} ~~ x^H P^H P x \leq a, 
$
where $ C \in \mathbb{C}^{L \times N} $, $ x \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1} $, $ P \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N} $, and $ M > N > L $.

They are not equivalent.
Consider the special vase of d = 0 and a > 0, with $C^HC$ being Hermitian positive definite (not merely positive semidefinite). Then x being the vector of zeros is (the only) optimal solution for P2. But that is infeasible for P1. Any feasible solution of P1 will have a worse objective value than the P2 optimal objective value of 0. So P1 and P2 are clearly not equivalent.

Hi Mark, thank you for your input! While I cannot make d = 0, I guess your ideas will help me to come up with a similar example. Also, another way this could be proven woulbe by finding the solutions for P1 and P2. Would you have any hints in this direction?

My answer shows the non-equivalence. I made d = 0 to provide an easy to see and understand example to see that. Whichever of P1 and P2 is the problem you want to solve is the problem you should solve. You will need to use a non-convex global optimization solver, of which there are several.

This depends on the problem inputs: $a$, $d$, $C$, and $P$ to determine if the constraint is active at the optimum.
For example two trivial cases:

If $C=P$ and $a=d$, then they are equivalent. The optimal solution is obvious, any x satisfying the equality constraint is a global solution.

If $C=P$ and $a>d$, clearly they are not equivalent.


